# Operación asincronica usando $q, Angular y Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, promesas

Solicito de su ayuda debido a que no he podido implementar un operación después del resultado de una `promise`. Los que necesito es solicitar los datos y cono los resultados hacer una comparación, el codigo es el siguiente:

Servicio

```
function filtroIntrumentoUno(infante) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var ref = firebase.database().ref();
    var messagesRef = ref.child("instrumentoUno/");
    var query = messagesRef.orderByChild("idInfante").equalTo(infante);
    deferred.resolve($firebaseArray(query));
    return deferred.promise;
 }
```

Controlador

```
instUnoServices.filtroIntrumentoUno($scope.infante.$id)
  .then(function (data) {
      $scope.instUno = data[0];
  })
  .then(function (data) {
      if (data == null) {
          //Si retorna null entonces haga algo
      } else{
          //de lo contrario hace otra cosa
      }
  });
```

Comment: El error se produce en el segundo `then`? En el primero si te llegan los datos?

Comment: @devconcept sip, en el primero llegan los datos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay una [regla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/return) en JavaScript que dice que cuando el cuerpo de una función no contiene una instrucción `return` esta automáticamente devuelve `return undefined;`.

```js
function undef() {

}

function defined() {
  return 'valor';
}

console.log('Sin return:', undef());
console.log('Con return:', defined());
```

Esto puede ser confuso ya que no hay error y a veces no es evidente en código.

*¿Qué impacto tiene esto en las promesas?*

Pues que cuando ejecutas un `then` este siempre permite seguir encadenando tantos métodos `then` como sea necesario y el resultado obtenido en cada uno dependerá del **resultado** de tu función asincrónica o del **valor retornado** por el `then` anterior. Este puede ser otra promesa o un valor cualquiera.

```
.then(function(resultado) {
    // "resultado" depende de la función llamada o then anterior
});
```

Recapitulando

```
funcionAsincronica().then(function(resultado) {
    // "resultado" es el valor obtenido por la función si se ejecuto correctamente
});

funcionAsincronica().then(function(resultado) {
    // resolvemos con un valor u objeto cualquiera
    return 'valor';
}).then(function(resultado2) {
    // "resultado2" será la cadena de caracteres 'valor'
});

funcionAsincronica().then(function() {
    return otraFuncionAsincronica();
}).then(function(resultado) {
    // "resultado" será el valor obtenido si "otraFuncionAsincronica" se ejecuta correctamente
});
```

En tu caso no tienes una instrucción `return` en el primer `then` por lo que el valor del parámetro `data` será siempre `undefined` para resolverlo simplemente sigue devolviendo el mismo objeto en los `then` siguientes.

```
instUnoServices.filtroIntrumentoUno($scope.infante.$id)
  .then(function (data) {
      $scope.instUno = data[0];
      // Devuelve lo mismo que te llego 
      // para que esté disponible en el siguiente then
      return data;
  })
  .then(function (data) {
      if (data == null) {
          //Si retorna null entonces haga algo
      } else{
          //de lo contrario hace otra cosa
      }
  });
```

Ten en cuenta que *usualmente* se debe englobar toda la lógica en un sólo `then` *a menos* que hayan operaciones asincrónicas.

Tu código es válido, pero si abusas de ese patrón (crear `then` sin una justificación) creas complejidad innecesaria y puede llegarse a considerar un antipatrón.

Comment: super genial la explicacion mil gracias por tu ayuda y aclaracion.

Comment: como podría manejar el tiempo de respuesta, lo que pasa es que si el internet esta muy lento se cumple la condición null, pero no es por falta de datos sino por el internet

Comment: @Gdaimon No debes preocuparte por los tiempos de respuesta. Si la llamada falla porque el internet está muy lento, el callback que se ejecutará es el `catch` no el `then`. En ese caso escribe la lógica que consideres necesaria en ese método notificando de un error (recomendado) o volviéndolo a intentar.

Answer (score 0):

Yo resolvería la promesa en el servicio y devolvería los datos al controlador donde realizaría la operación que deseas.

Sería algo como esto:

Servicio:

```
return llamadaAsincronaAlServidor()
.then(respuestaSatisfactoria, respuestaErronea);

function respuestaSatisfactoria (respuesta) {
  return respuesta.data
}
function respuestaErronea (error) {
  //código para manejar el error
}
```

Controlador:

```
function operacionConDatos () {
  return datosOperados
}
```